# Laravel: Difference between where and whereHas

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between the two methods where() and whereHas()? They both seem to be quite similar in the laravel documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `where()` behaves like a regular SQL `WHERE` query part.

The method `has()` uses foreign key relationships to return something which has something else. For instance, `Student::has('classes')->get();` would return all students who have classes.

The method `whereHas()` is like a regular `has()`, but it lets you put constraints on the search. Unlike `where()`, this is done on the child table rather than the parent one. Here's an example:

```
$students = Student::where('name', 'Pingu')         // constrains the students table
    ->whereHas('classes', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%physics%'); // constrains the classes table
    })->get();
```

In this highly realistic example, you'd want all students with a name of Pingu, who are taking some class in physics.

Comment: what if I want to add constraint by column in pivot table (not child table)? Can I use where in that closure?

Comment: Probably not, I don't quite remember. If I need that kind of querying ability, I usually make the pivot table into an intermediate model.